# Java: get rid of copy-pasted static methods usage

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, static-methods

I have a code that caught my eye. How can I simplify it?

```
abstract class A {}

class B extends A { //generated by Velocity
  static public Iterator<B> iterator() {...}
}

class C extends A { //generated by Velocity
  static public Iterator<C> iterator() {...}
}
```

And usage:

```
for (Iterator<B> i = B.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  sout(i.next().toString());
}
for (Iterator<C> i = C.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  sout(i.next().toString());
}
```

Is there a way for me to create some method, that will take Class extending A to iterate over it? Preferentially not to change class generation logic.

Comment: You are calling `B.iterator()` although it is not static. Is this a mistake?

Comment: A class that can return an `Iterator<T>` should usually implement `Iterable<T>`. Then instances of this class can also be used in *foreach* loops, like `for(B x : b) print(x);`. However, this would require the class generation to be changed, so in doubt, do it like Olivier Grégoire suggested.

Answer (score 1):

So first you could redefine your A class and add itterator there

```
abstract class A<T extends A> {
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {...}
}
```

if required made this method abstract;

Then you need to change definition of your classes `class B extends A<B>` and `class C extends A<C>`

other thing, instead copy your code where you are using iterator, you could wrap it into method

```
public   <T extends A<?>> void itterate(Iterator<T> itr) {
        for (Iterator<T> i = itr; i.hasNext();) {
            sout(i.next().toString());
        }
    }
```

then you cal it

```
itterate(b.iterator());
itterate(c.iterator());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible without touching to A, B nor C:

```
public static void doSomething(Iterator<? extends A> it) {
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    sout(it.next().toString));
  }
}
```

Then call:

```
B b = ... ; // Retrieve an instance of B
C c = ... ; // Retrieve an instance of C
doSomething(b.iterator());
doSomething(c.iterator());
```

With your edit in mind (`iterator()` becoming `static`), you can keep the method I wrote without changing anything. However the calls change like this:

```
// Don't create instances anymore.
doSomething(B.iterator());
doSomething(B.iterator());
```